# Dynamically formatting textbox for credit card expiration date

Tags: javascript, html

I know that I've seen a few websites use this before but I can't find any examples now.

What I want is a textbox where after the user enters the first two numbers (the month) a forward slash is added and then the user types the last two numbers (the year) but if they were to backspace it would skip over the forward slash (i.e. it simply isn't just injected into the textbox). How is this possible with javascript?

Edit: Below is what I've tried but then the user could click in the textbox and delete the '/' if they wanted to.

```
var expiresDateField = document.getElementById('j_idt8:ccexpires');
        expiresDateField.onkeydown = function() {
            var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
            if (expiresDateField.value.length === 2)
                expiresDateField.value = expiresDateField.value + " / ";
            else if (expiresDateField.value.length === 6 &amp;&amp; (key === 8 || key === 46))
                expiresDateField.value = expiresDateField.value.substr(0, 2);
};
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery masked input plugin for the same
[See working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SEXAj/3464/)

```
$("#date").mask("99/99");
$("#date").keyup(function() {
  //get the date
  var datevalue = $(this).val();

  //only if the date is full like this: 'xx/xxxx' continue
  if (datevalue.length == 5) {
    verifyDate(datevalue);
  } else {
    clean();
  }
});

function clean() {
  $('#msg').html('');
}

function verifyDate(datevalue) {

  if (datevalue != null || datevalue != '') {

    //split the date as a tmp var
    var tmp = datevalue.split('/');

    //get the month and year
    var month = tmp[0];
    var year = tmp[1];

    if (month >= 1 && month <= 12) {
      //clean the message
      clean();

    } else {
      $('#msg').html('Month is invalid.');
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: @jschwalbe Please mark this as the right answer if it helped you in solving your issue.

Comment: Is it now erroring out? The inputmask url is not being resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Use [inputmask](http://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask) and [moment](https://github.com/moment/moment).

lets say you want a 10 year date range from today's date dynamically...

include the jQuery.InputMask.js and moment.js library (CDN or self hosted)...

[CDN]

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/bindings/inputmask.binding.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js
```

then...

```
<input type="password" id="expires_mmyy" name="cc_expires" maxlength="5" />

$('#expires_mmyy').inputmask({
   alias: 'datetime', 
   inputFormat: 'mm/yy'
   min: moment().add(1, 'M').format('MM/YY'),
   max: moment().add(10, 'Y').format('MM/YY')
})

// this fixes an Android bug that will probably be fixed in the near future...
$('#expires_mmyy').attr('type', 'text')
```